# Crystal Report Load Report Failed vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have an `Error in Load report Failed`.

This is my code :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Application.StartupPath + "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Lastnato\IT58 PROJECTS\BRCPS\SoftEng ProjSystem\Reports\CrystalReport1.rpt"

    CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "{Lastname} = '" & TextBox1.Text.ToString & "' "
    CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

can you please help me.

Comment: Put a breakpoint and see what value this line produces and you will see that the path is incorrect: `Application.StartupPath + "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Lastnato\IT58 PROJECTS\BRCPS\SoftEng ProjSystem\Reports\CrystalReport1.rpt"`

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to use `Application.StartupPath` and a path that starts like: "c:\Users". Probably your Application Startup Path is already like "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Lastnato\IT58 PROJECTS\BRCPS\SoftEng ProjSystem"

If your reports are in the same folder as your .exe file, you probably want this line instead

```
'Not this (original)
'CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Application.StartupPath + "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Lastnato\IT58 PROJECTS\BRCPS\SoftEng ProjSystem\Reports\CrystalReport1.rpt"
'Which would end up looking like:
' "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Lastnato\IT58 PROJECTS\BRCPS\SoftEng ProjSystemC:\Users\user\Desktop\Lastnato\IT58 PROJECTS\BRCPS\SoftEng ProjSystem\Reports\CrystalReport1.rpt"


'Instead, just use the relative path
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Reports\CrystalReport1.rpt")
```

Also, I recommend using `Path.Combine()` because it easily takes care of putting one backslash (not two or zero) when it combines.